# Replacing Characters in String with a Double Quote

Tags: regex, asp-classic

This is my string:

```
<HOLDERS><ACCOUNTHOLDER Title="" Initials="" FirstName="" Surname="" Name="AN'A"N&D & TEST'S"I&X" CifKey="ANA"D.TSX000" CustomerType="2" PrimaryPan="00027272898"/></HOLDERS>
```

how do I replace the double quotes " in the Name and cifkey and replace them with

```
&quot;
```

while still maintaining the double quotes everywhere else in the string?

the output should be

```
<HOLDERS><ACCOUNTHOLDER Title="" Initials="" FirstName="" Surname="" Name="AN'A&quot;N&D & TEST'S&quot;I&X" CifKey="ANA&quot;D.TSX000" CustomerType="2" PrimaryPan="00027272898"/></HOLDERS>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct XML. If that's the case, it would be far better to use a library or tool that understands XML (such as the [MSXML component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx)) rather than trying to munge things together via strings and regexes. That way you're likely to get all of the escaping correct (i.e. you're current expected output still isn't valid because the `&`s should also be escaped).

Comment: Unfortunately I am dealing with really old code which I can't really change too much. The string is being passed into oDomDoc.loadxml(sXmlData) however the sXmlData which is the above string is not well formed..I need to do some Replacing.but cant work out how to change the " in the Name and CIfKey without affected the rest of the string and the other "...

Comment: Then you've got a mess and that's for sure. Are there any assumptions that can be made about the `"`s within the attributes? I.e. will they always be surrounded by alphabetical characters, as in your example (or, at least, never be followed by whitespace or `/`)?

Comment: I.e. worst case scenario - will you ever have to deal with an input like `Name="A" CifKey="B" Name="C" CifKey="D"` and then have to work out if the name is `A" CifKey="B" Name="C` and the CifKey is `D` or the name is `A` and the CifKey is `B" Name="C" CifKey="D`? If we can't work out which answer is correct, there's no way to tell a computer how to either.

Comment: It is a very tricky situation that is for sure. I ended up tracking back the code a long way into where it originally builds the string (took me 2 days to find) and managed to fix it at the source. Thanks for the comments though you managed to convince me that it was too difficult to fix at this leve

Answer (score 0):

I wrote all the passages just to be clear but you can make a function and reduce everything to few lines.

Probably isn't the cleanest way but start making it work and improve it after. Assuming txt is your string.

```
index1 = InStr(txt," Name=") 'space before Name is important not to confuse with firstName, Surname and so on...
index2 = InStr(txt, " CifKey=") 'space before Cifkey is important...
index3 = InStr(txt, " CustomerType=") 'space before CustomerType is important...

SubStrName = Mid(txt, index1 + 7, index2 - 1)
txt = Replace(txt,"SubStrName","##AAA##") 'modifing original string with placeholder which you should be sure is never inside the text
NewChunk1 = Replace(SubStrName,""","&quot;")
txt = Replace(txt,"##AAA##","NewChunk1")

SubStrCifKey = Mid(txt, index2 + 8, index3 - 1)
txt = Replace(txt,"SubStrCifKey","##BBB##")
NewChunk2 = Replace(SubStrName,""","&quot;")
txt = Replace(txt,"##BBB##","NewChunk2")
```